# Как сделать из двух div один?

Tags: html, позиционирование, css

Добрый день.
Есть такой код:

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
     <div>Текст, который расположится в блоке, который будет по средине страницы.</div> 
</div>
```

И такие стили:

```
#wrapper { 
     width: 100%; 
     background: #aaa; 
}

#wrapper div { 
     width: 1000px; 
     margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Т.е. как вы понимаете, я хочу получить текст в блоке (длиной 1000 пикселей и позиционированном по средине) на фоне, который находится по всей длине экрана. Интересно, возможно ли сделать тоже самое, но через один div, а не через два вложенных. 
Если просто прописать блоку ширину и позиционировать, то фон будет не на всю длину экрана.

UPD: вряд ли это возможно сделать красиво и не портя код. Вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 4):

**Так устроит?**

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper"> 
     Текст, который расположится в блоке, который будет по средине страницы.
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #aaa;
}

#wrapper {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #fff;
}
```

Элемент body, также как и другие элементы поддается стилевому оформлению. Конкретно в Вашем случае, мы просто задаем для элемента body 100% высоту, ширину и устанавливаем для него цвет фона. А что касается дочернего div'a, то для него устанавливаем ширину в 1000px, затем центрируем и задаем нужный нам background если он отличается от фона body.

Немного сумбурно получилось, но думаю, что мысль ясна...

Удачи.

Comment: Вы ничего не сделали нового. Просто назвали оборачивающий div по-другому. Не годится.

Comment: @cheremushkin, о чем Вы?

Вы хотели убрать один div - я его убрал. Опишите задачу более подробно... 

Если необходимо реализовать что-то вроде зебры (один блок с одним фоном, другой с другим), тогда другого варианта, кроме как использовать два div'a нет.

Можно конечно с JS заморочиться, но стоит ли оно того...?

Comment: @Astor, Вы просто поменяли оборачивающий div на body. Мне же body для других целей нужен, он уже выполняет те же самые функции, только для другого места на сайте.

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте *text-align: center* в стили wrapper-а

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #wrapper {
                background: #aaa;
                text-align: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            Text in the middle of page
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: я думаю что он не только текст в дивах держать собрался.

Comment: и ширину надо еще зафиксировать

Comment: Да, конечно не только текст. Не то.